# Java Repaints only every other guess

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

I have a function that prints how many guesses there are for a player.
Here is the code:

```
public void drawString(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawString("You have " + getN() + " guesses left", 400, 50);
    if (lastN != getN()){
        repaint();
        lastN = getN();
    }
}
```

My problem is that it repaints every other time. I mean:

**First it prints:** You have 10 guesses left
then it stays 10 when only 9 guesses left

**Then it prints:** You have 8 guesses left
ect. until there are 0...

how to make it change every time?

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: never-add change component state in the paint cycle (it's uncontrollable when that is called)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need to do :

```
if (lastN != getN()){        
    lastN = getN();
}
repaint();
```

`repaint` outside of `if` condition, now in this case `paint` will be called every time

Comment: it keeps re-painting itself all the time causing whole program to flash in that case i need it to be in if condition

Comment: then it will only `repaint` in case if condition is true, you can use a delay like `Thread.sleep` after `repaint` in above example

Comment: @HarmeetSingh `Thread.sleep` and the Event Dispatch Thread together is  simply not-done

Comment: @Robin of course, i am waiting for SSCCE to make more clarification.